# Error in file(file, *"rt"): cannot open the connection

Tags: r, directory, connection

I made a for-loop that loops through a folder. The folder is called *Ultrasonic data - Plots* and it contains subfolders. The names of the subfolders are consistent and the data in the subfolders as well. When I run the code it runs very well for the majority of the loop, but for some subfolders it gives an error.

The error is: file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection.

The answers that I have read normally state the problem as a wrongly states working directory. However, I think it is not the case in this example. Could anything else cause this error message?

I have already checked the consitency of the names of the subfolders and .txt data files within them.

```
'''R  
parent.folder <- "//home.org.aalto.fi/meijsl1/data/Documents/GAGS/Ultrasonic data/Ultrasonic data - Plots"  
sub.folders <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=FALSE)  
filt.folders <- sub.folders[grepl("SV-30-[^_]*_S[12]", sub.folders)]  

for(i in filt.folders) {  
  setwd(i)  
  AIC("SV-30", 20, 40) #This is a function that picks the S-wave onset of an ultrasonic signal  
}   #End for loop over all specimens
'''


'''PArt of the AIC function where the error occurs: (read.table)    
  for (n in 1:length(filelist)){  
    #  
    # Read the file into R  
    #  
    file.path('./out/Processed', basename(filelist[n])) -> procpath  
    read.table(file=procpath, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names = FALSE) -> temp  
    assign(paste(substr(basename(filelist[n]), 1, nchar(basename(filelist[n]))   - 4)), temp)  
'''
```

The code should be running smoothly, as it does for most of the subfolders, but apperantly there must be something wrong. I am out of ideas what it could be. Consistency was the only thing that could cause this trouble in my point of view. I hope anyone can help.

Cheers

Comment: Do you know which file raise the error ? You can check at first, open this file manually and after that, try to execute the command just with this filepath in the R console.

Comment: Hey Rafaelo, yes I have checked the file that caused the error. I ran it separately and it gave the exact same error. Now, I have spotted the mistake. Thank you for your reply!